# Persistent selected option on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to persist a selected option in a select element on the page reload. My select gets populated dynamically and once an item get selected I need it to append the value of the option to the URL and trigger a window.location to reload the page.

I am trying to do it with jQuery but would not be opposed to do only with plain JS if that's possible. This is what I've tried but the select option keeps getting back to the very first one on every page reload.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong here? Thank you!

```js
$(function(){
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('selectedProject');
    if(storedValue != null){
        $("#projectsList").first().find(":selected").removeAttr("selected");        
        $("#projectsList").find("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == storedValue) {
                    $(this).attr("selected", true);
                }
            });
    }
    $('#projectsList').change(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("selectedProject", $("#projectsList").first().val());
        window.location = window.location.href + "?project=" + localStorage.getItem('selectedProject');
    });

    $('#projectsList').change(function () {
         var currValue = $(this).val();
         localStorage.setItem('selectedProject', currValue );        
    })
    // set stored value when page loads
    .val(storedValue)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="projectsList" class="selectpicker show-tick project-list" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" data-width="35%">
   <option value="value1" data-tokens="value1">value1</option>
   <option value="value2" data-tokens="value2">value2</option>
   <option value="value3" data-tokens="value3">value3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `storedValue != undefined || storedValue != null` is always `true` after `var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('selectedProject') || '';`. `localStorage.getItem('selectedProject') || ''` always returns a string.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in a stack snippet.

Comment: @jabaa where can I provide a code example like jsfiddle where it accepts jQuery code?

Comment: Snack snippets are very similar to jsfiddle and support jQuery. Edit your question. You'll see a button to format code and next to it there is a button to create a stack snippet.

Comment: I've tried here but because of the window.location not sure how that would work on a code playground. Can you please let me know? https://codepen.io/jbalsamo/pen/OVdOPV

Comment: Why can't you create a stack snippet? You should also fix the problem I described in my first comment. Have you tried to debug your code using your debugger or `console.log` debugging? Please add some debugging details.

Comment: Sorry that was my first time using stack snipper. I've edited my posted and added to it. I tried to debug using console.log, the values are being parsed and appending to the URL perfectly (as well as it's saving in the localStorage). The problem is that on the page reload, no matter what option I select it always set to the very first option rather than the one I selected.

Comment: Why haven't you fixed the bug I described in my first comment?

Comment: @jabaa thank you for your help so far. I've removed the string assignment to get only the value from localStorage.

Comment: Now, you have two different codes in your question and `storedValue != undefined || storedValue != null` is still somehow strange. `storedValue` can't be `undefined`. It's is either a string or `null`, but `null != undefined` returns `true`. This could be confusing.

Comment: Why do you do a page reload with `window.location`. You could use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) with [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) or [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) instead to rewrite the URL.

Comment: How would I do that? I am new to JS, my end goal was to select an option in the dropdown and reload the page with the option value appended in the URL as a query parameter. example, host/path?project={option_value}

Comment: Both links contain working code examples. But in addition you should read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). I like the paragraph: _"StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story."_ Please add your debugging results. What value do you get for _"storedValue"_ after a page reload? What happens next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `.change` handlers, and the one that reloads the page, always sets the localstorage to the first item option in your list.

Just using a single `.change` handler should solve your problems.

```
  $("#projectsList").change(function () {
    var currValue = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem("selectedProject", currValue);
    window.location =
      window.location.href + "?project=" + localStorage.getItem("selectedProject");
  }).val(storedValue);
```

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele I came to realize that the problem that I was running into is related to the selectpicker library. With a plain select and the js script above it works perfectly. Still debugging what is causing with that particular library since I need live search in the dropdown.